# how can we use foreign key when deleting data in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables which are refered by foreign key...
I will delete the data from first table using primary key...and also i want to delete that refered data from second table when delete the first table data...
is there any other way to delete data from both tables in single operation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem by using set tag in mapping file..this is my code it's working fine now

i added these code in xml file

```
<set name="teamMatch" cascade="delete" inverse="true" table="tbl_team_match">
 <key><column name="match_id" not-null="true" /></key>
 <one-to-many class="TeamMatch"/>
 </set>
```

and added these code in java file

```
MatchBean match = (MatchBean) hibernateSession.load(
                        MatchBean.class, Integer.parseInt(id));
                hibernateSession.delete(match);
```